# Aluminum parts on motorcycle oxidized after washing

Tags: motorcycle, corrosion, aluminum

I washed my used motorcycle the first time since I've bought it this summer, and soon after noticed that oxidation appeared on some aluminum parts. It's **definitely** wasn't there before and surely this motorcycle had been washed plenty of times before me. All I did was sprayed down the bike with pressure washer from a distance (8 feet/2.5 meters), then washed it with a sponge and soap, rinsed with pressure washer from a distance, and wiped it down with a cloth.

So what might have cause the oxidation after my washing?

Comment: Aluminum always has an oxide layer. It may be porous and absorb stuff discolor it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this is either one of two things:

1) the soap used was not suitable - may have had a bleach or some other chemical which may have attacked the aluminium surface,

2) these are just simple deposits left on the surface by impurities in the water.

You should clean it again and see whether the surface itself has been damaged - if it has you need to get it re-treated - painted, varnished or whatever the surface treatment was originally.